# Firebase database querying

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, querying, uid

I am using firebase database to retrieve data, actually I want to filter data on the basis of the 'cCompany' of the user. I am using an edittext field which passes in the data(sCompany) entered to the below function into 'filt'. So when I try to make a query using this 'filt', then it filters the data only if that cCompany is present in the topmost user's uid. If its present in other uid, then its not filtering the data. Please solve this problem.

```
private void addEventFirebaseListener1(final String filt) {
    //Progressing
    DatabaseReference usersRef = 
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String userId = ds.getKey();

         DatabaseReference userIdRef = FirebaseDatabase
.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userId).child("Complaints");
          Query q =userIdRef.orderByChild("cCompany").equalTo(filt);
     ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) 
             {


          for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) 

            {
       Generalperson user = postSnapshot.getValue(Generalperson.class);
                            list_users.add(user);


                        }
                        if (list_users.size() != 0) {
                            ServiceComplaintAdapter adapter = new 
 ServiceComplaintAdapter(ServiceComplaintsActivity.this, list_users);
                            list_data.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } else {

                            list_data.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            k.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                        }

  circular_progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }

                    @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }

                };
                q.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);


  }
```

[image: Database image]

Comment: What you want as result ? please explain in brief

Comment: I want to filter data on the basis of cCompany of Complaints child.... for example , I will enter xnx in the edittext and pass the entered value into filt, so now I want to show the result of only those complaints which have cCompany as xnx

Comment: Currently what you get as result?

Comment: Currently i am to able to filter the data on the basis of cCompany if that cCompany is present in the complaint child of first user of the json tree. like - xnx is present in the first user's complaint child, so if i am trying to filter..it filters all the data whose cCompany is xnx....but if i try to filter using some other cCompany which is not present in the complaint child of 1st user (but present in other users's )..then its not getting filtered.